# Cam recorder with sound - Pet monitoring

Tags: gratis, linux, monitoring, webcam

I'm looking for a software that can record video and sound at home all day. Then, at the end of the day, I want to quickly be able to see if there was some noise at some time of the day (my dogs barking, to be precise), and watch why that happens.

I have 2 PCs: one with Ubuntu, another with Fedora. I'm a power user, so don't hesitate to show complex solutions.

I'd like free (as in free beer) software if possible.

Answer (score 1):

I use WebcamXP when I'm going on vacation, it's really simple to use.
You can enable motion detection, and many other functions.

The problem it's only compatible with Windows XP, Vista, 7, 8, Server 2003, 2008 and 2012 ...

http://www.webcamxp.com/home.aspx

[image: WebCamXP Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

If you use a camera that produces an [RTSP data stream (such as a Foscam-compatible device)](http://foscam.us/forum/how-to-use-rtsp-and-https-for-hd-cameras-t4926.html), it is trivial to record video using `ffmpeg`:

```
ffmpeg -i 'rtsp://username:password@camera_url:port/videoMain' -codec copy output_file.avi
```

You can then review the file later using your choice of open source video players.

If you want to use an audio program (such as [Audacity](http://sourceforge.net/projects/audacity/)) to generate an amplitude graph of the audio (and quickly barking or loud noises), extract the audio track:

```
ffmpeg -i output_file.avi -vn -acodec copy output.wav
```

You could then determine offset times in the video stream and seek quickly to the locations of interest using e.g. VLC.